# SQLlite inner join query giving giving absurd results

Tags: mysql, sql, sqlite

I am trying to run an example where I want to know the manager name of each employee but i can't see all the rows.

**Table structure**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS t1 (
    staff_number INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    fname VARCHAR(20),
    lname VARCHAR(30),
    gender CHAR(1),
    country VARCHAR(30),
    manager_id INTEGER,
    joining DATE)

[(10, 'piyush', 'Bansal', 'M', 'Canada',16,'2014-03-28'),
 (16, 'gillbart', 'Gates', 'M', 17,'United States','1980-10-28'),
 (17, 'amezaa', 'Craft', 'F', 19,'Japan','2016-03-14'),           
 (19, 'Marbles', 'IsaDog', 'F','United States',20, '2018-11-03'),
 (12, 'Maks', 'Demin', 'M','United States',16,'2018-11-03'),
 (20, 'Sean', 'Hartrich', 'M','United States',19,'2014-02-16'),
 (24, "Sam", "theBrit", "M","United Kingdom",10,'2014-02-16')]
```

**Query**

`SELECT e.fname ,m.fname FROM t1 e INNER JOIN t1 m ON e.manager_id = m.staff_number`

**Output**:

```
('piyush', 'gillbart')
('Maks', 'gillbart')
('Marbles', 'Sean')
('Sean', 'Marbles')
('Sam', 'piyush')
```

**The entry for Bill and Brena as employee and manager are missing here. Any clues what is happening here??**

**Expected Output**:

```
('piyush', 'gillbart')
('Maks', 'gillbart')
('Marbles', 'Sean')
('Sean', 'Marbles')
('Sam', 'piyush')
('gillbart','amezza')
('amezza','Marbles')
```

Comment: make sure your data is consistent with your question, I can't see any user with name "Rishabh" (appears in your current output)

Comment: My bad.i updated it @mangusta

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two lines of you script are have a mistake:

> (16, 'gillbart', 'Gates'   , 'M', 17      ,'United States','1980-10-28'),
>
> (17, 'amezaa'  , 'Craft'   , 'F', 19      ,'Japan','2016-03-14'),

The column value for **country** has **manager_id** instead.